# Php and session for login and logout

Tags: php, forms, session, cookies, authentication

I have a problem I can not solve. I did a login page in html that goes to accesso.php two parameters: username and password. Once that occurs if the username and password are correct allows me to add data to this particular login. If I go back to the login form and I sign with another username and password in the fields to delete certain records (line 112) There are no records of previous login and update themselves doing a refresh. Do you know help me with the sessions? here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
#main{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
background-color:grey;
/*Stile shadow dietro css3*/
/*-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 100px #FFF;*/
/*-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px #FFF;*/
/*box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #FFF;*/
/*consiglio sempre di specificare le dimensioni del main*/
width:500px;
height:950px;
margin-top:110px;

/*Bordi arrotondati css3*/
-moz-border-radius: 85px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;

}

#centro{
position:absolute;
margin-left:70px;
margin-top:20px;


}
h1{

color:red;
}

p{

color:red;
}

</style>
</head>
<?php



$archivio=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$select=mysql_select_db("disco");
$username = $_POST["utente"]; //username 
$password = $_POST["password"]; //password

session_start();
$provaT = $_SESSION['username'];//nome del locale non so come lo trova

echo $provaT;//stampa a video nome del locale


mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); // per caratteri speciali
$sql = "SELECT * FROM locali WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'"; //query verifica se username e password coincidono
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)//se è presente
{



   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $row['nome']; // la sessione prende il nome della colonna nome del db


   ?>

<body background="texture_disco.jpg">
<div id="main">
<div id="centro">
<?php
echo "<h1>Benvenuto ".$row['nome']."</h1>";

$space = str_replace(' ',"",$provaT);
$risultato=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $space");
?>

<form method="post" action="prova.php" >
<h5>titolo</h5>


<input type="name" name="nome" value="" id="nome">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<textarea name="des" rows="20" cols="45">
Scrivi qui la tua recensione (Max 1000 caratteri ...)

</textarea>
<br>
<br>
<input type="name" name="link" value="" id="link">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Inserisci Evento">

</form>
<form  method="post" action="delete.php" >
<select name ="record">
<?php

while($ok=mysql_fetch_array($risultato))
{

echo "<option value='".$ok['_id']."'>".$ok['nome']."</option>";

}

echo '<h1>'.$ok['nome'].'</h1>';
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Elimina evento" name="delete">
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Elimina sessione" name="delete">

  <?php }
}

else
{
header("Location: errore.php");

}
$gammaT=mysql_close($archivio);





?>

</html>
```

This is the file deleted the gate where the entries in the database

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<style type="text/css">

#contEst{
top:70;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
margin-top:-30px;
background-image:url('sfondo.jpg');
/*Stile shadow dietro css3*/
/*-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 100px #FFF;*/
/*-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px #FFF;*/
/*box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #FFF;*/
/*consiglio sempre di specificare le dimensioni del main*/
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin-top:100px;

/*Bordi arrotondati css3*/
-moz-border-radius: 85px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;



}


</style>
</head>






<body>
<div id="contEst">
<?php

session_start();

$provaR = $_SESSION['username'];
echo '<h1>'.$provaR.'</h1>';
$archivio=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$beta=mysql_select_db("disco");
$space = str_replace(' ',"",$provaR);
$risultato=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $space");
$canc = $_POST["record"];
$spazi_titolo =mysql_real_escape_string($canc);

$via=mysql_query("DELETE FROM $space WHERE _id='$canc'");
 session_destroy();
mysql_close($archivio);

////////////////



/////////////////
echo '<h3>'."Voce cancellata correttamente".'</h3>';
//echo("$provaR"); stampa nome locale
 //echo '<a href="http://localhost/disco/Accesso.php"><input type="submit" value="Torna alla Home"></a>';


if(!$_COOKIE){
 echo '<a href="http://localhost/disco/Accesso.php"><input type="submit" value="Torna alla Home"></a>';

}

else{

echo "errore";
}

?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and in this file "test.php" I add the entries in the database

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>

<?php
session_start();
$provaT = $_SESSION['username'];
$title = $_POST['nome'];
$des = $_POST['des'];
$link = $_POST["link"];
$archivio=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$beta=mysql_select_db("disco");
$spaziT =str_replace(" ", "", $provaT);
$spazi =mysql_real_escape_string($des);
$spazi_title =mysql_real_escape_string($title);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $spaziT(nome,descrizione,link) VALUES('$spazi_title','$spazi','$link')");


echo "Nuovo evento creato";

  mysql_close($archivio);

   echo '<a href="http://localhost/disco/icone.html"><input type="submit" value="Torna alla Home"></a>';
?>




</html>
```

Comment: Please formate your code.

Comment: Show us what is in `delete.php` and `prova.php`

Answer (score 0):

No matter what happens this will not work:

```
header("Location: errore.php");
```

header only works if you haven't outputted any text to the browser...

Read here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Also you never closed these tags

```
<body background="texture_disco.jpg">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="centro">
```